# É possível alterar o tipo da variável em Java?

Tags: java, variáveis, tipagem

É possível alterar o tipo da minha variável em Java? Por exemplo, criei uma variável `x`, sendo ela um `Double`:

```
double x;
```

Quero continuar usando a minha variável `x` porém sendo ela agora um `int`:

```
int x;
```

Isso é possível?

Comment: Pode-se fazer casting. Mas a variável contiuará double e com seu valor como declarado, e também pode haver perda de dados.

Comment: Aqui é tipagem forte mano! Não essas papagaiadas de linguagenzinhas dinâmicas (desculpem, não resisti :P).

Comment: Alguma resposta resolveu o problema? Você sabe que pode aceitar uma, né?

Comment: Quero o contrafile com fritas, mas troque a carne por frango e as fritas por purê ... Não faz sentido a não ser uma curiosidade.

Answer (score 10):

Não é possível e não existe razão para fazer isto.

Em tese seria possível criar um tipo, ou usar `object`, para armazenar qualquer tipo, mas raramente isto faz sentido. De qualquer forma o tipo do dado será mais especializado que o tipo declarado na variável.

A definição de uma [variável](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/181332/101) é uma reserva de espaço na memória e o estabelecimento de um contrato que sempre haverá um tipo de informação lá. Então você não pode trocar seu tipo. Pelo menos não em Java e outras linguagens ditas **estáticas** (o termo correto). Se fosse uma classe seria possível criar um objeto de um tipo compatível (derivado) porque a variável é só uma referência para o objeto real que tem um tipo específico, isto é possível por causa da [indireção](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/181032/101).

Algumas "soluções" foram postadas e aparentemente você achou uma solução "mágica". Recomendo não fazer nenhuma delas, nem mesmo a que você parece ter achado como solução. Esconder o real problema não é uma solução. Procure uma solução para seu problema. Se for o caso poste outra pergunta com o problema real que você quer resolver.

Me parece que você está tentando aplicar uma solução para um problema que não a exige. Defina bem seu problema e procure a melhor solução para ele. Podemos ajudar nisto se postar uma pergunta com mais detalhes do problema real.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Java/Conceptual.md).

Comment: +1 Por: não existe nenhuma razão para fazer isto.

Answer (score 7):

A resposta curta (como já dita) é **não**.

Para entender o motivo note que existem *Linguagens fortemente tipadas*, *Linguagens fracamente tipadas* e *Linguagens não tipadas*

- **Linguagens fortemente tipadas** são linguagens em que a declaração do tipo é obrigatória. Todas as variáveis têm um tipo específico que tem que ser explicitado. `Java`, `C#`, `Fortran` e `Cobol` são exemplos deste tipo.
- **Linguagens fracamente tipadas (Dinamicamente tipadas)** são aquelas em que durante a execução do programa podem alterar o tipo de dados contido em uma variável. Permitem que o programador não tenha de fazer conversões de tipos (cast). `PHP`, `Javascript`, `Ruby` e `Python` são exemplos deste tipo.
- **Linguagens não tipadas** são aquelas em que existe apenas um tipo genérico ou mesmo nenhum tipo de dados. Entre estas estão a `Assembly`, `BCPL`, `Perl` e algumas versões de `Forth`.

*Fonte:* http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linguagem_tipada

Se o motivo é migrar um software de uma linguagem para outra, você deverá reescrever o software conforme o tipo da linguagem, portanto dificilmente você conseguirá migrar de uma **Linguagem fortemente tipada** para outra **Linguagem fortemente tipada** e praticamente será impossível migrar de uma linguagem **Linguagem fortemente tipada** para **Linguagem fracamente tipada** sem reescrever o software inteiro.

Answer (score 6):

## SIM

Mas será bem trabalhoso. Este é um trabalho que envolve bastante magia negra e feitiçaria maligna. Algumas entidades das trevas terão que ser invocadas para o mundo dos vivos.

O que você precisará fazer é algo parecido com que o [projeto lombok](http://projectlombok.org/) faz por debaixo dos panos. Ele faz tudo o que eu descrevo a seguir e é exatamente por isso que ele tem superpoderes que nós meros mortais não temos.

Basicamente o que você vai ter que fazer é criar um processador de anotações que sequestre o compilador. Isso é possível porque no caso do *javac* e do compilador do eclipse, eles são escritos em java e o processador de anotações roda na mesma JVM que o compilador. Para sequestrar o compilador, você tem que obter acesso as árvores sintáticas do código e sair fuçando e mexendo nelas a vontade. Como a API do compilador é interna e não deveria ser usada publicamente, para obter o acesso a ela você vai precisar usar todo o tipo de cast, reflection, violação de regras, malandragem e gambiarra que for preciso. Vale até manipulação de bytecode nas classes do compilador.

Após sequestrar o compilador e ter domínio total sobre as árvores sintáticas, tudo o que você tem que fazer é mexer com estas árvores para aceitar que você possa redeclarar variáveis no mesmo escopo e usando um tipo diferente. Afinal de contas, neste momento, o compilador já é seu e você faz o que você quiser com ele.

Boa sorte!

E se você quiser seguir este caminho, então seja bem vindo ao lado negro da força!

Mas... Porque mesmo que você quer fazer isso?

Comment: Kkkkkk só queria tirar o ".0" que aparece quando peço para exibir o número"1" como double... Aparece assim: 1.0... Mas já resolvi isso atribuindo a uma String kkk Valeu

Comment: @victor Não resisti, o lado negro da força é mais forte Luke. Essa tua resposta é a resposta pra mim cara.

Comment: lkkkkkkkkkjkkkkk

Comment: https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/499/o-que-%C3%A9-o-problema-xy

Answer (score 5):

Não, as variáveis em java são imutáveis, porem, **apenas por curiosidade**, você pode da uma "roubadinha", trocando o objeto mas mantendo a variável.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        Object a = 1;
        a =  new StringBuilder("ola");
        a = 666;
        System.out.println(a);

}
```

Bom quase tudo no java é objecto, então se você quer fazer uma suruba com java esse é o caminho das trevas

> Não recomendo a utilização desse tipo de técnica, de qualquer forma você está mudando o objeto e não o tipo, o problema é que o tipo e controlado pelo objeto, profundo não ?

Answer (score 3):

Tente assim:

```
double x;

int newX = (int) x;
```

Sendo `newX` o resultado da conversão e `(int) x` a *double* que esta sendo convertida...

Comment: Não mestre, a pergunta foi como trocar o tipo da variável, mantendo a mesma variável.

Comment: Bom, entao nao vejo sentido em ele querer fazer isso...

Comment: Esse é o ponto, isso acontece quando migramos de linguagem, fiz os mesmos questionamentos quando migrei do python -> java, onde o tipo pouco importava.

Comment: Esta foi a única resposta que capturou a necessidade do AP, a qual, como a maioria das necessidades em software, era mais simples do que a maioria supôs. Nós programadores adoramos complicar. +1