# C# Desafio Troca de valores de variaveis

Tags: c#, variáveis, tipagem

Recentemente fiz um desafio bem simples :

> Trocar o valor de duas variáveis sem utilizar uma terceira variável.

```
int a = 5;
int b = 3;

a += b;     // a = 8
b = a - b;  // b = 5;
a -= b;     // a = 3;
```

Ele é simples pois são operações aritméticas.

Contudo estava pensando em como fazer caso fossem *strings*.

```
string a = 'Stack';
string b = 'Overflow';
```

Ate pensei em algumas soluções, mas estas se aplicam a [linguagens de tipagem fraca](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/51312/%C3%89-poss%C3%ADvel-alterar-o-tipo-da-vari%C3%A1vel-em-java#answer-51332) :

#### Exemplo JS

```
var a = 'Stack';
var b = 'Overflow';

a = a+'|'+b;      // a = 'Stack|Overflow';
a = a.split('|'); // a = ['Stack', 'Overflow'];

b = a[0];  // b = 'Stack';
a = a[1];  // a = 'Overflow';
```

Como poderia resolver este desafio com *string*?

Comment: Tem alguma restrição do que pode fazer?

Comment: @bigown não, só não pode usar outra variável.

Comment: Então não me interessa, essas coisas não levam a lugar algum :P Fazer de um jeito pior quando pode fazer do jeito melhor não me agrada. A resposta existente é suficiente.

Comment: @bigown O teste verdadeiro (com `ints`) tinha um intuito matemático, portanto ele fazia um certo sentido :P

Comment: @jbueno exatamente, embora acho que seria melhor feito com operador de bit. Essa é uma coisa maluca a se fazer. É bem lento e destruidor de memória :)

Comment: @bigown eu não sou um grande conhecedor de C#, ate pensei em mais alguns métodos por conversão para binário, mas ai teria de se alterar o tipo da variável. Eu sei que você é um grande conhecedor, gostaria de sua participação, para intuito de aprendizado.

Comment: Não tem o que fazer com essa restrição. Pode ser que tenha solução melhor que a presentada, mas nenhuma será boa. A solução óbvia e boa é usar uma variável temporária. Ao contrário de um inteiro que tem tamanho pequeno e a cópia integral não gera grande *overhead*, `string` gera valores diferentes. Então não está criando uma variável nova, mas **está criando valores novos**, que é muito pior. Se existisse uma motivo para fazer isto eu entenderia, mas a restrição artificial faz com que isso seja uma curiosidade sem sentido prático.

Comment: Compreendi, no caso eu estaria utilizando mais memoria do que se fazer com uma auxiliar.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tem várias formas de fazer.

A que eu pensei primeiro foi

```
string a = "Teste";
string b = "Overflow";

a += "|" + b;

b = a.Split('|')[0];
a = a.Split('|')[1];

WriteLine($"a = {a} - b = {b}");
```

A saída será:

> a = Overflow - b = Teste

Veja funcionando no [.NET Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/DGjkn0)

Comment: Muito bom, não cogitei esta. :/

Comment: Estou a ver mal ou isto não é mais do que a "tradução" para C# do exemplo, em JS, apresentado na pergunta?

Comment: Não tinha prestado atenção, mas é sim. Acredito que isso não seja nenhum problema @ramaral

Comment: Não vi como um problema apenas achei que o AP não se devia ter contentado com uma resposta que se resume à "tradução" do que tinha na pergunta.

Answer (score 1):

Seguindo exatamente a mesma ideia que o jbueno, mas usando dos artifícios de linguagens de tipagem fraca, onde no C# pode ser alcançado essas vantagens com o dynamic.

```
dynamic a = "Teste";
string b = "Overflow";

a = (a + "|" + b).Split('|');

b = a[0];
a = a[1];

WriteLine($"a = {a} - b = {b}")
```